# Yodlee get user account details iOS

Tags: ios, yodlee

I have logged into `cobrand` and `user` for my `yodlee` account and am able to fetch the list of `providers`. I am not using a server at my end of the app. I am not able to login the user through the Add Account Post Method in the Providers section. I intend to get the Users mutual funds data by logging in the user and displaying the data in my app. Is this realisable as I am unable to figure out the callBack after successful Login. Any help would be appreciated. [APIs Yodlee](https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/providers/getSuggestedSiteDetail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [POST /providerAccounts](https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/providerAccounts/newAddAccount) API for initiating add account. Please note this API will just initiate add account, and you need to check the status of this process, using GET API; you can use the API flow mentioned [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/API_Flow/Add_Account_With_ProviderAccount).

You can use [Fastlink 2.0](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0) instead of using APIs if you want to quickly integrate add account process.

Comment: thanks for the response. I need to get the User's bank account balance after the account has been added. Can you please guide me as to how to get it done.

Comment: Once, your add account process is completed successfully, you can call following API- https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/accounts/getAccounts This will get you all the accounts, in its related information. You can also use other filters to play around.

Comment: yes I have explored the website and its quite extensive. The problem I was facing was due to miscommunication with the Backend developer.

Comment: I have set up a dummy account. I need to get the mutual fund data for that I believe MFA is required. Can you tell me as of how to do MFA from iOS

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan As mentioned in my answer you can execute APIs step by step as mentioned in the flow- https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/API_Flow/Add_Account_With_ProviderAccount and this also guides you about handling MFA. Once done, you can call https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/holdings/getHoldings API to get Mutual Funds.